# Tool to track #include dependencies

Tags: c++, c, header

Any good suggestions? Input will be the name of a header file and output should be a list (preferably a tree) of all files including it directly or indirectly.

Comment: This is similar to (but not a duplicate of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326/how-should-i-detect-unnecessary-include-files-in-a-large-c-project

Comment: It is not about a "favorite" includes are shown nicely in gcc, but msvs does not. So we (I) are looking for any tool.

Comment: Why do I keep finding "off-topic" questions so helpful?

Comment: @jfritz42: This should be given the "Comment of the Year" award! How can one moderator label a question "off topic" when there are so many topics and so many users?

Comment: I wanted to note that there are plenty more tools for dealing with `#include` dependencies like [cpp-dependencies](https://github.com/tomtom-international/cpp-dependencies), [iwyu](https://include-what-you-use.org/), and [dep-matrix](https://github.com/NavicoOS/dep-matrix/blob/master/dependencydatabase.py) which is a pretty naive tool written in python.

Comment: @jfritz42 The numbers are clear: 123 votes and 62 favourites. Many people see it this way. Weird SO standards. I also doubt that such questions would have the same great answers on SuperUser.

Comment: There's a new tool called [`cpp_dependency_graph`](https://github.com/shreyasbharath/cpp_dependency_graph), it's still in early development but I have a number of improvements planned. Disclaimer - I am the author of this tool.

Comment: I wouldn't mind calling the question "off-topic" if we were still allowed to post new answers.

Comment: @Alex-Myers I tried to edit this question to be on-topic. As far as I can see, i did the minimal; remove 'tool suggestions' and add 'what have you tried so far'. If you disagree with my way of fixing the question, could you fix it yourself?

Comment: @jfritz42 because they are usually from a time when SO had way less rules, focused a lot less on policing users, didn't give incentives for the community to label everything off-topic or duplicate just for being remotely similar, and was still not infested with "why do you need to know that" type of comments. In a word, because SO was a LOT better and more useful as whole when those old off-topic questions were asked

Answer (score 173, accepted):

If you have access to GCC/G++, then the [`-M` option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) will output the dependency list.  It doesn't do any of the extra stuff that the other tools do, but since it is coming from the compiler, there is no chance that it will pick up files from the "wrong" place.

Comment: `-H` even gives a tree!

Comment: `-MM` skips system headers

Comment: Also with the `-o` option the compiler gonna write the output to file instead of stdout.

Comment: @SamB This only works if there are no errors, and prints to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. Otherwise, this option is more general.

Comment: I would give a thousand points to this-

Comment: clang also supports this very same option.  Check out [clang's command line argument page](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-m).

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer because it answers a different question. The question was for the inverse : what files use the specified header, not what files are used by the specified file.

Answer (score 96):

Thanks to KeithB. I looked up the docs for cl.exe (VS2008) and found the /showIncludes flag. From the IDE, this can be set from the property page of any CPP file.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: This is *extremely* useful in solving some very hard compile errors/warnings. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is also **extremely** handy when trying to optimize precompiled headers!

Comment: When working in VS, I think this is the quickest solution to solve my problem~ :-)

Comment: This does not seem to work, if some header does include a std c header e.g. `math.h`

Answer (score 30):

For a heavy weight solution, you should check out [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).  It scans through your code base and comes up with a website, effectively, that documents your code.  One of the many things it shows is include trees.

If you were looking to be able to plug the output of this tool into some other process, then this may not work for you (although doxygen does output to other formats, I'm not real familiar with that feature).  If you simply want to eyeball the dependencies, though, it should work great.

Comment: How does that determine "unnecessary"???    I have "foo.cpp", it includes (directly or indirectly "bar.h"...Will the removal of bar.h cause *any* differences in the compiled output of foo.cpp??   If the answer to this is no, then it is an unnecessary include.

This is *hard*.... foo.h may #define something that is #if in a completely different .h file....

Answer (score 20):

I've played around with a tool called [cinclude2dot](http://flourish.org/cinclude2dot/). It was pretty useful in getting a handle on a rather large codebase when I came to work here. I've actually thought about integrating it into our daily build eventually.

Comment: This tool works exceptionally well. I had trouble with g++'s -M and doxygen.

Comment: I wrote a python script to read the output of cinclude2dot and get all the dependency in a map and then do depth-first-traversal to finally output a forest of sources. The forest that does not have any `.cc/.c/.cxx` file in that(only the `.h` files in it) may be redundant.

Answer (score 14):

Good news: [redhat Source-Navigator](http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/) (runs on Windows too). Of course, compiler switches (mentioned earlier) have superior parsing and I'm not sure how this will handle MFC, Qt and their magic keywords.

[image: redhat Source-Navigator]

Answer (score 13):

First, cinclude2dot.pl is a perl script which analyses C/C++ code and produces a #include dependency graph as a dot file for input into graphviz.

http://www.flourish.org/cinclude2dot/

If you don't want to go the way of that sort of manual tool, then the hands-down by far winner is in my opinion a tool known as "IncludeManager" from ProFactor.

http://www.profactor.co.uk/includemanager.php

There's a free trial, and it is awesome. It's a plug-in for Visual Studio that's totally integrated so double clicking on something over here takes you to the place where it is included over there.

Tooltip mouseovers give you all the info you would want, and it lets you drill down / up, remove whole subtrees you don't care about, view representations other than graphs, cycle through a list of matches for this and that, it's wonderful.

If you're quick about it, you can refactor the #include structure of a large projects before the trial runs out. Even so, it doesn't cost much, about $35 per license.

For what it does, it is just about perfect. Not only #include graphs but also cross project dependencies of shared files, impact on build times, detailed properties in grids, perfect.

Comment: I have successfully used IncludeManager in my C project. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Kinda suspicious.

Comment: No longer at that link...

Answer (score 7):

Building on [KeithB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42513/2877364), here is GNUmake syntax to automatically 1) generate the dependency files, 2) keep them up to date, and 3) use them in your makefile:

```
.dep:
    mkdir $@
.dep/%.dep: %.c .dep
    (echo $@ \\; $(CC) $(IFLAGS) -MM $<) > $@ || (rm $@; false)
.dep/%.dep: %.cpp .dep
    (echo $@ \\; $(CXX) $(IFLAGS) -MM $<) > $@ || (rm $@; false)
DEPEND := $(patsubst %.dep,.dep/%.dep,$(OBJ:.o=.dep))
-include $(DEPEND)
```

(Make sure to change those indents to hardtabs.)

Answer (score 5):

You can also check out *makedepend*:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend

http://www.xfree86.org/current/makedepend.1.html

Answer (score 4):

[Understand for C++](https://www.scitools.com/) should be able to help you: it builds a database that you can access from Perl.

Comment: Understand is commercial, but it is incredible IMO.  You can try it for free.

Answer (score 2):

cscope (http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) does this in a standalone xterm, and also can be used inside your favorite editor - it has great emacs and vi/vim support.