# Do you know tool building tree of include files in project\file?

Tags: c++, scripting, include

Say, I'd like to have a tool (or script?) taking project (or .h file) and building searchable tree of "includes" included into it (of included into of included into and so so on). Is there exist something like this? Should I write this by myself [of course I am :), but may be somebody had it already written or may be has an idea how to get it]?

Comment: Related (Visual Studio): http://stackoverflow.com/q/1137966/711006

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely sure this is what you're after, but you can easily get a list of includes by generating the post-CPP-processed file from the base c file, and grepping out the file/line number comments, e.g., using gcc

```
gcc -E main.c {usual flags} | grep '#' | cut -d' ' -f3 | sort | uniq
```

where main.c is your base c file.

Comment: This is how I have done it in the past (except with MSVC).  The hard part of automating is getting the correct compile flags, from either projects or makefiles) as these can effect what files are included when.

Comment: Thanks. In common, "I'm after" .h file (consequence of includes)  in big and old project causing failures. I am interested in MSVC, but if I not receive better answer - this will do.

Comment: The VS CL.exe compiler has /E & /P flags which generate the processed output to stdout and a file respectively. You can get grep, cut etc from one of several (free) Unix tools for Windows packages around, e.g. http://unxutils.sourceforge.net.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, a slightly more useful output than the gcc/g++ -E output alone would also used the -H flag (instead or in addition to):

`g++ -H {my -I and other flags} -E -o /dev/null file.cpp`

here is a sample output, tree structure helps figure out who included what
as a bonus it also lists at the bottom which files may benefit from an include guard

```
. generated/gen-cpp/File.h
.. /usr/include/thrift/TProcessor.h
... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/string
.... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h
..... /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
..... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/os_defines.h
...... /usr/include/features.h
....... /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
........ /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
....... /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h
........ /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
........ /usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h
..... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/cpu_defines.h
.... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stringfwd.h

...
```

Comment: it's great, but how I can use it for Windows tools?

Comment: Sorry @bgee I do not have any of those handy

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, [doxygen](https://www.doxygen.org/) can do this.

Comment: How does it handle preprocessor directives and include paths?

Comment: @sehe: I haven't had the chance to play with doxygen in a long time. You will have to try. From what I remember, though, its support for weird configurations was rather impressive, and its development rapid.

Answer (score 1):

[**Include Finder**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3478/Include-File-Hierarchy-Viewer) is a pretty useful tool.  It has some bugs, and hasn't been updated in a while, but the author does provide the source, so you can modify it to your liking.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT has the [Include Browser](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_include_browser_view.htm) under Window --> Show View --> Other... --> C/C++ --> Include Browser.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a tool called `include gardener`, which can be found here:
https://github.com/feddischson/include_gardener
This gives you the include tree in `dot` or `graphml (xml)` format. But it does not consider other preprocessor statements like `#if`, `#else`, `#endif`.