# View the "include" tree in a C/C++ project

Tags: c++, c, tree, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you know tool building tree of include files in project\file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226044/do-you-know-tool-building-tree-of-include-files-in-project-file)

Currently reading the Minix source code (I'm interested in operating system & driver programming), I am looking for a program that would help me understand the tree view of this project.

I found a piece of software called [Include Finder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/includefinder.aspx), which, though it doesn't show dependencies in trees, is helpful for understanding the structure.

Does anybody know a good program to scan a project & view the dependency tree ?

Thanks !

Comment: Eclipse can do that for a given file of the project (Window->Show view->Include browser). I am not sure it can handle the complete include tree of a project: it is probably quite messy...

Comment: There exists also a tool called `include-gardener` which can be found here: https://github.com/feddischson/include_gardener
It gives you the include tree in `dot` or `graphml` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Eclipse CDT. It has [Include Browser](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_include_browser_view.htm).

Comment: Ah... Didn't expect Eclips to be a solution... once again !
Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try Doxygen with Graphviz installed. If doxygen is configured properly, it will return each included file for each source.