# How to find all files that constitute a translation unit in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm using a header only library and would like to include only the part of the library that I'm actually using.

If I include one of the library's headers how can I find all the other headers that are included by the library? Or phrased more generally: how can I find all files that make up a C++ translation unit? (I'm using g++ on Linux.)

## Edit: Possible approaches with gcc (answers summary)

- gcc -H produces output of the form:

  ```
  ... /usr/include/c++/4.6/cmath
  .... /usr/include/math.h
  ..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h
  ..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_valf.h
  ```

  You have to filter out the system headers manually, though.
- gcc -E gives you the raw preprocessor output:

  ```
  # 390 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
  # 38 "/usr/include/assert.h" 2 3 4
  # 68 "/usr/include/assert.h" 3 4
  extern "C" {    
  extern void __assert_fail (__const char *__assertion, __const char *__file,
        unsigned int __line, __const char *__function)
        throw () __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));
  ```

  You have to parse the linemarkers manually. See: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html
- gcc -M produces a Make file for the given source file. The output looks as follows:

  ```
  object.o: mylibrary/object.h /usr/include/c++/4.6/map \
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_tree.h \
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h \
   /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h \
  ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you know tool building tree of include files in project\file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226044/do-you-know-tool-building-tree-of-include-files-in-project-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [gcc -H](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-H-957).

Answer (score 3):

`g++ -M somefile` to get a makefile that has all files somefile included as dependencies for somefile.o.

`g++ -MM somefile` the same, but doesn't list system headers (e.g. anything in `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include`).

What do you need this for? If it's for dependency tracking, the above should suffice. If you, on the other hand, want to do some crazy thing like "I include this header and that header includes this header, so I don't need to include it again" - don't. No, seriously. Don't.

Comment: That only gives me the headers that are directly included.

Comment: @BernhardKausler Are you sure? Check again. It gives me all directly or indirectly included headers when I try it.

Comment: @BernhardKausler `-M` gives all of the files the compiler reads to compile the source file.

Comment: @Cubic and James: You're right. I tried the -MM, that removed all headers of installed libraries. The -M option works as you say.

Answer (score 2):

You could obtain the preprocessed source using GCC's `-E` flag, then grep it for `#include`. I'm not aware of any other way for source files to find their way into a translation unit, so this should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Unfortunately the "#include"s are gone after the preprocessor. But you can recover that information from the linemarkers inserted by the preprocessor. See: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html

Comment: Could you please update your answer accordingly so that I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 2):

With g++ (and most Unix compilers, I think), you can use `-M`.  For other compilers, you'll need `-E` or `/E`, capture the output in a file, and post-process the file using your favorite scripting language.  (I do this in my makefiles, to build the dependencies.)