# Get include tree of GNU makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu

In an existing GNU Make build system, I'd like to see a tree of the makefile includes.  How may I do this?  Like [Do you know tool building tree of include files in project\file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226044/do-you-know-tool-building-tree-of-include-files-in-project-file) but for GNU Make rather than C and C++.

A related but slightly different capability I'd be interested in: being able to put $(info ...) statements in a makefile and have it print out a backtrace of includes for that info statement.

Comment: Is parsing the output of `make -d` an option?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a list of included makefiles, a `$(info Included files: ${MAKEFILE_LIST})` at the bottom of the main makefile fits the bill.

However, if you do want a tree, then you'll have to replace all `include <file>` with `$(call include,<file>)`. The `include` function would be something like:

```
space :=
space +=
${space} := ${space}

stack := $(firstword ${MAKEFILE_LIST})

define includefunc
  stack := $(subst ${ },|,$(strip ${MAKEFILE_LIST} $1)) ${stack}
  $(info INCLUDES $(firstword ${stack}))
  include $1
  stack := $(wordlist 2,$(words ${stack}),${stack})
  MAKEFILE_LIST := $(subst |, ,${stack})
endef

include = $(eval $(value includefunc))

$(call include,1.mak)
$(call include,_1/1.mak)
$(call include,folder/Makefile)

.PHONY: all
all: ; echo $@ success
```

Comment: Use of spaces in variable names (`${space} := ${space}`) is not permitted in recent versions of GNU Make: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2012-01/msg00052.html

Comment: The way bobbogo has done it it will still work; from the GNU make NEWS file: Second, variable names can no longer contain whitespace, _unless you put the whitespace in a variable and use the variable_