# Identify which file has included some particular header file

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2005, header, include

Sometimes with a complex header structure it happens some header is included, but it is hard to tell where from.

Is there some tool (depedency viewer?) or a method how to find the "inclusion stack" (which source / which header / which header / ...) is including one particular header file?

If the header file is included multiple times, finding first inclusion is sufficient, finding all inclusions is a welcome bonus.

Comment: grep is not enough, because of indirect inclusions (this is what I meant by a complex header structure, perhaps I should be clearer).

Comment: Or use a cross-referencer (a.k.a. 'grep on steroids') such as [OpenGrok](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+opengrok/).  Although that still won't help you find indirect inclusions.

Comment: [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) can produce include graphs, but it can be pretty slow to parse very large codebases.

Comment: @Neil: grep won't help with headers that `#include` other headers. And if there is conditional inclusion, calling grep again on the results of the first grep will not give useful results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Someone has posted about it but I can't find this answer.
So, In VS, go to your project properties. Choose Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Advanced / Show Includes and set "yes".

then compile you cpp file. It looks like this:
cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

In the output window after compiling you will see:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: stlport_project, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>stlport_project.cpp
1>Note: including file: D:\src\hrs_rt_059.00\HRS\modules\src\libs\src\external\stlport\5.1.7\stdio.h
1>Note: including file:  D:\src\hrs_rt_059.00\HRS\modules\src\libs\src\external\stlport\5.1.7\stl/_prolog.h
1>Note: including file:   D:\src\hrs_rt_059.00\HRS\modules\src\libs\src\external\stlport\5.1.7\stl/config/features.h
```

and so on

EDIT: reference to the same question [Displaying the #include hierarchy for a C++ file in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137966/displaying-the-include-hierarchy-for-a-c-file-in-visual-studio)

Comment: `g++ -M stlport_project.cpp`. Check it.

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov Do you have any idea how to do the same in QtCreator?

Answer (score 8):

The header you are searching for may not be directly included into the source file. You need to 'preprocess_only' the code. This can be done in g++ by using the -E option; I don't know enough about visual C to know what the exact specification is there but if you look in the help for 'preprocess' you may come up with something.

Answer (score 6):

A somewhat hacky approach (but one which should work on any platform/toolchain, without needing a separate dependency analyser) is simply to add a `#error` at the top of the included header - you will then get a compilation error from the first `.cpp` file which includes it.

Comment: Nice and "portable" (no special tools needed) idea. A drawback is some headers (e.g. standard libraries) may be read only for you, or touching them can cause excessive rebuild as a result of them being frequently used.

Comment: @Suma: if you want to avoid modifying a standard header, put your own temporary copy with `#error` added early on the include path.

Answer (score 1):

### Visual Studio /showIncludes

Directly in the Visual Studio I have found an option called [/showIncludes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk%28VS.80%29.aspx) - the output is textual only, but indented in a way which makes reading it quite easy:

```
Note: including file: /*..path.anonymized..*/\TCMalloc\windows\config.h
Note: including file:  /*..path.anonymized..*/\memalloc\tcmalloc\windows/port.h
Note: including file:   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\windows.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\excpt.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\crtdefs.h
Note: including file:      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\sal.h
Note: including file:      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\vadefs.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\stdarg.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\windef.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\include\winnt.h
Note: including file:      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\ctype.h
Note: including file:       C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\crtdefs.h
```

### ProFactor Include Manager

There is also a VS add-in called [Include Manager](http://www.profactor.co.uk/includemanager.php) which seems to provide the needed functionality in a very nice visual way.