# How to find all the files that use a particular header in a specified directory on Linux?

Tags: linux, makefile, header

I have huge directory with makefiles, .c, .h .cpp etc. The final output (binary) is built using make.

To do that I have to find and investigate the source files that use `<aio.h>` and `<execinfo.h>` headers. So how do I find the files that use `#include <aio.h>` and `#include <execinfo.h>`

Comment: Grep or a grep-like.

Comment: If you need to auto-generate build dependencies you should probably have a look at [this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`mkdep`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mkdep&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+5.3-RELEASE)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify which file has included some particular header file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3438600/608639)

Answer (score 0):

For browsing big code, cscope or ctags is used. Both needs to generate database. For cscope it can be done by command cscope -b-q -k and later cscope-d will give console menu for search options. Find or grep will be slow for browsing of big code.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.c (or*.h)' -exec grep "thing_to_Search_for" '{}' \; -print
```

This command helped me achieve the results I needed.