# What is RpcNdr.h

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

And where does Microsoft get away with

`#define small char`

You can't just add reserved words to the language and quietly include them in a platform SDK!

And more importantly how do I get rid of it!

edit : how to find what is being included where and by what in Visual Studio - [Displaying the #include hierarchy for a C++ file in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137966/displaying-the-include-hierarchy-for-a-c-file-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @unapersson - it could come with a little note saying - this SDK will add another sdk which will break a whole bunch of your code.

Comment: @Martin - I'm curious about why your build is including this in the first place.

Comment: @Steve - so am I! I have the build set to v100 and this header is in the v7.0 sdk. Is there an tool in vs2010 to tell me the chain of includes?

Comment: @Steve - judicious use of WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137966/displaying-the-include-hierarchy-for-a-c-file-in-visual-studio - now I just have to persuade the library to fix their includes!

Comment: It's a maze alright.  In the meantime I am adding +1 to your question, since I did not know about the annoyance tag before today.  Thx.

Comment: I suggest you stay away from the C# and ".NET" framework, as you may need therapy if you do. ;-)  I'm already proving to my management all the functional cr*p that is ".NET" and not my program; such as the Serial Port.

Comment: Identifiers like *small* were chosen back in the early 90s by the Distributed Computing Environment standard, created by the Open Software Foundation.  A group of, drumroll, Unix vendors.  The group is still around, now named The Open Group.

Comment: @Hans - I wouldn't mind if they did things like _dcom_our_secretsauce_small - but 'small' is rather a common word. Plus a compiler message in a template saying that char isn't allowed in '< >' wasn't exactly helpfull

Comment: The preprocessor wasn't invented by Microsoft either.  Complaining about this doesn't get you anywhere.  Dropping RPC does, pick a higher level protocol.

Comment: @Hans - I wasn't picking RPC. I was using a library that happened to include "windows.h". Including "windows.h" on a windows machine shouldn't break C++, redefining min, max was bad enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say whether you wanted to get rid of the header include or of #define.

If you want to get rid of the include but don't know where, you could try to define the include flag in your header above where the SDK includes are listed.

```
#define RpcNdr.h //find the real flag in the header
#include "sdk.h"
```

If it is just the #define of 'small', then how about putting this in your headers right after the list of SDK includes.

```
#ifdef RpcNdr.h //find the real flag in the header
#undef small
```

Comment: A nice suggestion, but there is no guarantee that Microsoft will keep the header file or include guard symbols the same between SDKs and revisions of SDKs.

Comment: although it's not really the solution (a savage beating for MSFT and the library writers) it's useful info so I accepted it.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of the interface definition for the [RPC NDR engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373526%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (for RPC and DCOM marshalling).

Answer (score 1):

Well on my SDK it's described as "Definitions for stub data structures and prototypes of helper functions."

Comment: What a brilliantly helpful description!