# How to see all header files included by a cpp file in VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying the #include hierarchy for a C++ file in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137966/displaying-the-include-hierarchy-for-a-c-file-in-visual-studio)

I have a cpp file that includes multi-level header files (nested), and so difficult for me to know exactly what final header files are included. It apparently includes one header file, but I want to know where is that header file actually included (must be included in some other header file which is included by this cpp file).

How can I get a list of header file map included by compiler?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `/showIncludes` switch to the compiler. Then it will list all includes for the cpp files.
More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hdkef6tk%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).