# Any way to list header files used to compile each cpp file?

Tags: visual-c++

I got this compilation error in VC++ 2010 pro. Confusing thing to me is that I didn't include windef.h file nor any thing related to Microsoft SDK so I'd like to find which cpp file needs that header file for compilation. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 error C2011: 'HDC__' : 'struct' type redefinition
 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\windef.h(267) : see declaration of 'HDC__'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying the #include hierarchy for a C++ file in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137966/displaying-the-include-hierarchy-for-a-c-file-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [/showincludes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) compiler option for that.