# C++ OpenGL: Error gl.h included before glew.h

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently trying to write a little game with OpenGL. I got 2 classes:

- CoreEngine: for managing the Window, rendering, updating and so on
- Mesh:       for creating and managing meshes

Includes from CoreEngine.h:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vector>

#include "RenderingEngine.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
```

Includes from Mesh.h:

```
#ifndef _MESH_H_
#define _MESH_H_
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <string>
```

The reason is that I need functions from OpenGL in CoreEngine.h and in Mesh.h, but when I try to compile I get this error:

```
Fehler  1   error C1189: #error :  gl.h included before glew.h
```

I can't find a way, to prevent this error and to have OpenGL functions in both classes at the same time.

Comment: Any other `#include`s in the .cpp file which includes these headers? IOW, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Do you use precompiled header?

Comment: No precompiled headers and no other .cpp file which includes these headers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check if you have precompiled headers enabled (stdafx.h) - If you do, Don't. - In fiveteen years of software development I've only had one project that needed precompiled-headers. And even there it caused endless junior developers a headache.

Secondly, Check your individual CPP Files, it's possible you may find something such as

```
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include "mesh.h"
```

Finally As a first and last resort (for visual studio users) such as yourself you can display the list of all include statements, and the order they where included: [using /show includes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk(VS.80).aspx) - [See this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137966/displaying-the-include-hierarchy-for-a-c-file-in-visual-studio)

You may very-well find that some other library includes gl.h at an earlier point in your program (such as a graphics import library, or even a mathematics library (such as glm). Using the import-graph for this problem is the *reccomended* approach.

Comment: I disabled stdafx.h, but the error occurs again. Checked the "Include statements" but only these to classes are using the includes from glew.h

Comment: Have you deleted stdafx, and disabled the precompiled header option?