# Error Cannot open include file: 'GLES2/gl2.h': No such file or directory suddenly appears

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community

I've compiled my project many times over, both in release and debug configuration. Suddenly, an error appears:

```
Cannot open include file: 'GLES2/gl2.h': No such file or directory
```

This is a Qt project in Visual Studio 2017 Community with the [Qt add-in](https://wiki.qt.io/Visual_Studio_Add-in), using Qt 5.6.1-64.

I tried to search on google but there seems to be no advice that applies to this issue.

Comment: Your project worked before with that configuration(VS 2017, add-in, Qt 5.6.1-64.)  suddenly not working?

Comment: Did you change the Qt version from one using ANGLE to one using desktop OpenGL?

Comment: Yeah, I compiled on the same computer with the same settings in the same IDE three days ago and no problems occured. I am totally lost. I tried to rebuild but the issue persists.

Comment: It's a long shot but... try remove all debug/release folder and build again.

Comment: I found out that it's related to QTXlsx library. I'll document my steps, maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will document my steps for fixing this, it may help even if you have a different issue.

1. I watched which `cpp` file triggers the error
2. I commented it out completely, then re-added lines until error appeared
3. It was triggered by an `#include` statement
4. I enabled the [Include tree output from the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1138045/607407)
5. I found that the include comes from `QtXlsx` library which includes `<QtGui/QtGui>` through `C:\Qt\5.6.1-64\include\QtXlsx\QtXlsxDepends`. Note that we use GUI in this project, so there must be additional issue that causes this.

I commented out `#include <QtGui/QtGui>` from the `QtXlsxDepends` file. I noted this to myself to find the *real* cause of the error.

However everything compiles and works after this change. I will improve this answer after further investigation.

Answer (score 3):

I suffering the same problem. solved by adding this Include :

```
$(QTDIR)\include\QtANGLE
```

I found this solution by notice that project created by Qt Creator can be build without error. And find this include in qmake generated Makefile.