# How to make Visual Studio (C++) show "included by"-chain?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When there's a build error in a header file included by a series of include files from a .cpp file, how do I make visual studio show the whole chain of include files?

For example,

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'abc.h': No such file or directory
```

I'd like it to also print something like

```
included from 'xyz.h', included from 'efg.h', included from 'main.cpp'
```

Comment: @Evg It is not really a duplicate because this question asks about printing include chain, rather than complete hierarchy.

Comment: @user7860670 is correct, there is a fundamental difference in asking "includes what", and "included by what"

Answer (score 4):

You can use `/showIncludes` option, it can be found at `C/C++` -> `Advanced` section. It will dump a complete include tree though.

Comment: Under `Tools->Options->C/C++->Advanced` there's no option called `Show Includes` in VS2015. Can I look elsewhere?

Comment: Found it. There's a duplicate post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137966/displaying-the-include-hierarchy-for-a-c-file-in-visual-studio?rq=1