# How know the exact file the symbol comes from

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, include, c-preprocessor

I have a question regarding the include files.

Suppose you are using a define coming from windows headers. Of course, you can know what is the exact header which defines the macro. But the question is can we get the `include` chain and know which path causes the macro to be included?

E.g. I have the following structure

```
windows.h // a windows header defines a macro

header1.h <- windows.h // a <- b means a includes b
header2.h <- windows.h
header3.h <- windoes.h
header4.h <- header1.h, header2.h
header5.h <- header1.h, header4.h, header3.h
```

As you would expect, the real example can be a lot complicated with tones of macro definitions and `ifdef`s.

Now in our `example.cpp` we `#include "header4.h"` or `#include "header5.h"` or both together ant we use the macro in `windows.h` in our code. How to know what is the include chain?

E.g. for this example it could be `header4.h - header1.h - windows.h`

Comment: Related [Displaying the #include hierarchy for a C++ file in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137966/displaying-the-include-hierarchy-for-a-c-file-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes, it is related somehow. But I'm about easy functionality to just see the hierarchy. If I go through your suggestion, I have to compile the source, look where the header file is, then get the hierarchy. Although I didn't manage to find it in this way.

Comment: That's why I said it as related, instead of duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

With gcc 6.3.0 you can use a `#pragma` trick

```
$ cat so62875940.c
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma message "so62875940.c"

int main(void) {
    puts("foo");
    return 0;
}
$ gcc so62875940.c
so62875940.c:2:9: note: #pragma message: so62875940.c
 #pragma message "so62875940.c"
         ^~~~~~~
```

Then follow the includes order...

Answer (score 2):

I think this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-maps-for-cpp?view=vs-2019&viewFallbackFrom=vsmac-2019) may help you. You could select `Architecture->Generate Graph of Include Files/Generate Code Map for solution without Building`.