# Tool to Map #include's

Tags: c++, include

Is there a tool available which will take a set of source files and map (in graphic fashion) how they are linked via #include?

I would like to see where there are any circular references.

Comment: Wow. Great question, Changeling!
I do a lot of C programming in college, and this could save my sanity in the future.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies/43382#43382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Red Hat source navigator](http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/). Strongly recommended.

[image: Red Hat source navigator]

Comment: I have to say this is a very strong tool. Thank you for pointing it out. Changed to accepted answer!

Answer (score 5):

I believe doxygen:

http://www.doxygen.org/

with graphviz installed:

http://www.graphviz.org/

will do it.

Answer (score 2):

gcc(1) can produce dependency files. They are intended to be used by make(1), but they are relatively easy to parse. Use 'gcc -M -MF file' or 'gcc -MM -MF file'.

Comment: you can probably feed these to graphviz as well, since you want graphical output