# gcc, include file dependencies

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Is there option (or some utility) to generate graph of dependencies for given file?  I am trying to track down who brings an include file into compilation unit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to track #include dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `gcc -MM` would work?

Comment: Also, the gcc option `-H` option is helpful.