# 'class" has a previous declaration here

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I cannot for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

**My makefile:**

```
all: main.o rsa.o
    g++ -Wall -o main bin/main.o bin/rsa.o -lcrypto

main.o: src/main.cpp inc/rsa.h
    g++ -Wall -c src/main.cpp -o bin/main.o -I inc

rsa.o: src/rsa.cpp inc/rsa.h
    g++ -Wall -c src/rsa.cpp -o bin/rsa.o -I inc
```

**My main class:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rsa.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //RSA rsa;
    return 0;
}
```

**My .cpp:**

```
#include "rsa.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

RSA::RSA(){}
```

**My .h:**

```
#ifndef RSA_H
#define RSA_H

class RSA
{
    RSA();
};
#endif
```

**I'm getting the following error:**

```
In file included from src/main.cpp:7:0:
inc/rsa.h:7:7: error: using typedef-name ‘RSA’ after ‘class’
/usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:140:23: error: ‘RSA’ has a previous declaration here
```

I feel like I've tried everything but I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> /usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:140:23: error: ‘RSA’ has a previous declaration here

From the error message it seems that You have a symbol name clash with another class named `RSA` defined inside OpenSSL.
There are two ways to overcome the problem:

1. Change your class name or
2. Wrap up in a namespace if you want to keep the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler found a typedef for RSA in the ossl_typ.h file, which is indirectly #included when you compile your program. I can think of at least three solutions:

1. Change your class name to something else.
2. Put your class in a `namespace`.
3. Figure out why the OpenSSL header is included in your build. After looking around, I found [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685457/header-file-inclusion-static-analysis-tools) which says that `gcc -w -H <file>` will show you the files which are #included. From there you might be able to remove the dependency on the OpenSSL headers.