# ‘ostream’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

As the title suggests I'm experiencing a rather odd problem. When I try to compile a sample source code (that uses libotb) I keep getting errors like the one in the title. What is weird is that `#include <iostream>` is present in the said source/header where the error is reported.

On the other hand if I extract the code from the said file and create a separate source and compile it with `g++ <source_file>` it works, but if I compile with `g++ -I<path_to_libotb_headers> <source_file>` I get the same error, although the source file doesn't include anything from said path.

As stated in the below comments, this issue happens with simply

```
#include <iostream>   

int main                                                                                
{
    std::cerr << "Test";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is the question? Some code we haven't seen contains an error. There's not much we can do about that

Comment: did you use `using namespace std` or `std::` prefixes?

Comment: @jalf: Does the code have any relevance?

Comment: @EarlGray: I've reduced it to `#include <iostream>                                                                                      

int main()
{
    std::cerr << "Test";
    return 0;
}
`

Comment: This answer might be useful to verify that you actually included the intended headers when changing the include-path  (g++ -H) http://stackoverflow.com/a/6685693/104774

Comment: look at "<path_to_libotb_headers>" and see what headers are in there - I agree with stefaanv that examining what the includes used actaully are is your best way forward...

Comment: Does maybe `path_to_libotb_headers` lead to a header called `iostream` so that one gets picked up?

Comment: @DanielFischer: for some odd reason it seems that there was indeed a file called iostream, but it didn't cross my mind and due to the fact that there were almost 2k files in that folder I didn't spot it

Comment: Add `-H` to gcc or g++ arguments to print out paths to all used header files. Look through the listing to spot obvious problems, like `iostream` not in the standard path.

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <ostream>
```

should fix it. Under C++11, `#include <iostream>` is supposed to pull in all of `<ostream>`, but prior to C++11 you had to do the individual `#include`s.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

int main ()

- you missed the () :)

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your includes all closed their namespaces -- your include may accidentally be declared in a namespace if a previous header did not close its namespaces.

You can also attempt to locate this problem by moving the std includes earlier in the include list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Arduino programmer don't forget that Arduino does NOT have any 
normal ‘ostream’ stuff build-in.
But there is libraries offering similar functions.

PS.  Bear in mind that there is good reasons that streaming type stuff is not included.