# What's going on with clang's include priorities?

Tags: clang, include-path

My command:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -I/Users/me/project/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv \
-I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -std=c++11 -O3 -M -c \
/Users/me/project/src/program.cpp | grep opencv
```

`program.cpp` has:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"
```

Output:

```
  /opt/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp \
  /opt/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h /usr/include/assert.h \
  /usr/include/math.h /opt/local/include/opencv2/core/version.hpp \
  /opt/local/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp \
  /opt/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp \
  /opt/local/include/opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp \
  /opt/local/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp \
```

However, there exists: `/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp`, and `/usr/local/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp`.

Using the `-v` flag, clang tells me:

```
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/me/project/include
 /usr/local/include/opencv
 /opt/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

Why is clang including from `/opt/local/include` instead of `/usr/local/include`, despite `/usr/local/include` coming first in the list of `-I` directories in the command? Why is `/usr/local/include` pushed down the priority list.

Comment: try to reverse the order of inclusion and you will get your answer

Comment: @user2485710 You mean put `-I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include`? That does not fix things. `/usr/local/include` still gets listed *after* `/opt/local/include` in the list of include paths produced by `-v`.

Comment: than they don't contain the same headers, have you tried this way with a minimalistic source code ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6685693/2485710

Comment: The content of the search directories should not affect the search order produced by -v. (And, they do contain the same headers, even though it doesn't matter.) I don't think you understand my question.

Comment: that test is just verbose compilation, forget about what you about your files, just give that source code to `gcc' and see what files are really used.

Comment: @user2485710 I demonstrated what files are really used by using `-M` in the first output that I show. -M produces the list of include files that are really used. Also "just verbose compilation" *does* list the include directory search directory. It is not irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the default search path for `#include` by:

```
gcc -Wp,-v -E -
```

(give the `-v` flag to the preprocessor).

Your directories (given with `-I`) are searched before the standard list, in the order you give them.

You give `/usr/local/include` explicitly, and `gcc` disregards your instruction because it will be added (as a system directory) later on anyway; thus the directories are searched in the wrong order. If you really want to control the directories searched yourself, use `-nostdinc` and give them all. That is extremely fragile.

To have two sets of header files with the same names is a very bad idea (as you found out). No way to clean up *that* mess?

Comment: So, I shouldn't have opencv 2.4.8 installed at /opt/local/lib, and the development branch installed at /usr/local/lib? I thought that it would be easy to choose between these by specifying the order of include and library directories at the command line. It seems this is only a very bad idea *because* of this behaviour of gcc and clang.

Comment: *"To have two sets of header files with the same names is a very bad idea..."* - Huh? That's the standard way to update an outdated library. The OS has their old copy of `<favorite lib>` in `/usr/{include|lib}`, and you put your updated copy of `<favorite lib>` in `/usr/local/{include|lib}`. Its required for some libraries, like OpenSSL. Apple still ships an EOL/Abandoned OpenSSL 0.9.8.