# Catalina C++: Using <cmath> headers yield error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace

Tags: c++, macos, clang, toolchain, macos-catalina

After upgrading to Catalina from Mojave, Setuping: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk in the env.

I'm unable to compile a program that use `<cmath>` header.

I tried changing CFLAGS, CCFLAGS, CXXFLAGS to point to the MacOSSDK Location that change nothing

```
Scanning dependencies of target OgreMain
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f OgreMain/CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/build.make OgreMain/CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/build
[  0%] Building CXX object OgreMain/CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/src/OgreASTCCodec.cpp.o
cd /Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/build/OgreMain && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -DOgreMain_EXPORTS -D__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0 -I/Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/OgreMain/src/OSX -I/Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/OgreMain/include/Threading -I/Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/OgreMain/src -I/Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/build/Dependencies/include -I/Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/OgreMain/include -I/Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/build/include -I/Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/OgreMain -isystem /usr/local/include  -Wall -Winit-self -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations -Wno-unused-parameter -Wshadow -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override  -msse -O3 -DNDEBUG -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden   -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/src/OgreASTCCodec.cpp.o -c /Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/OgreMain/src/OgreASTCCodec.cpp
In file included from /Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/OgreMain/src/OgreASTCCodec.cpp:29:
In file included from /Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/OgreMain/src/OgreStableHeaders.h:40:
In file included from /Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/OgreMain/include/OgrePrerequisites.h:309:
In file included from /Users/roman/Downloads/ogre-1.12.2/OgreMain/include/OgreStdHeaders.h:10:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:314:9: error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:315:9: error: no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:316:9: error: no member named 'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'?
using ::isfinite;
```

for example the macro: `isless` is present in the global namespace and on my computer:

```
➜ cat math.h | grep "isless"

#define isless(x, y) __builtin_isless((x),(y))
#define islessequal(x, y) __builtin_islessequal((x),(y))
#define islessgreater(x, y) __builtin_islessgreater((x),(y))
➜  pwd
/usr/local/include
➜
```

Even the cmath header include it:

```
➜ cat /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath | grep "math.h"
#include <math.h>
```

And my command line have the option `-isystem /usr/local/include`

This should work...

Comment: Does `xcode-select -p` match where Xcode is located?  Can you change the code to `using std::signbit;`, likewise for the others?  Are you compiling as C++11 or later?

Comment: Compiling as C++ 11. I cannot change the code, it's an external dependencies !

yes `xcode-select -p` match where `XCode` is located.

Comment: That's not good.  The code is trying to do `using ::signbit;` and the symbol isn't in the global namespace, it is in `std::` namespace.  I presume likewise with the others (I didn't chase them down).

Answer (score 20):

I'm curious: What compiler are you using? What's the value of `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT`?

I'm fairly convinced this is the result of a wrong `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT`. I had the problem you're describing when using python bindings for clang (where CMake doesn't manage the compiler call), but I managed to recreate the error in CMake by doing:

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT "")  # Reset.
```

I solved my problem by following the answers to this question: [Cannot compile R packages with c++ code after updating to macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313047/cannot-compile-r-packages-with-c-code-after-updating-to-macos-catalina).

To summarise: On Catalina, `/usr/include` is purged and protected by SIP. Thus, any project that expects the C headers to be found there will fail to compile. If I remember correctly, Apple recommends to file bug reports to projects that expect C headers in `/usr/include`.

You must point the build system of the code you're trying to compile to the right headers:

(1) Make sure Xcode is up to date. There's no telling what an outdated Xcode on Catalina might do to your build environment.

(2) Use the `-isysroot /sdk/path` compiler flag, where `/sdk/path` is the result of `xcrun --show-sdk-path`. I'm not sure what CMake's best practice is, but try doing

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT /sdk/path)
```

or

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "[...] -isysroot /sdk/path")
```

If that solves the problem, you may want to look for a better way to do this in CMake.

Of course, if you're adventurous, you could also disable SIP, as suggested in the answer to my question: [/usr/include missing on macOS Catalina (with Xcode 11)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372032/usr-include-missing-on-macos-catalina-with-xcode-11)

Comment: `set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT ...)` goes into `CMakeLists.txt`, not the shell.

Answer (score 18):

I am having the same problem while trying to target iOS (both on my MacBook Air and on GitHub Actions runner) and here are a few more thoughts on the problem even though I'm not familiar enough with Apple's ecosystem to suggest a proper solution. The original command line was coming from CMake in cpprestsdk, but once I boiled it down to essentials, here is a short repro.

1. Create file `cmath-bug.cpp` with the only line in it:

```
    #include <cmath>
```

2. Run (newlines in front of some arguments are for reading convenience, remove them)

```
clang -v -x c++ -target arm64-apple-ios13.2 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ 
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk 
-isystem  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include
-c cmath-bug.cpp
```

When I run it, i get the familiar to many facing the same issue:

```
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)
Target: arm64-apple-ios13.2
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-ios13.2.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name cmath-bug.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=13.2 -target-cpu cyclone -target-feature +fp-armv8 -target-feature +neon -target-feature +crypto -target-feature +zcm -target-feature +zcz -target-feature +sha2 -target-feature +aes -target-abi darwinpcs -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -ggnu-pubnames -target-linker-version 530 -v -coverage-notes-file /Users/myuser/Projects/C++/cmath-bug.gcno -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1 -Wno-framework-include-private-from-public -Wno-atimport-in-framework-header -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/myuser/Projects/C++ -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 204 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=ios-13.2.0 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o cmath-bug.o -x c++ cmath-bug.cpp
clang -cc1 version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16) default target x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
ignoring duplicate directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
In file included from cmath-bug.cpp:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:318:9: error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:319:9: error: no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:320:9: error: no member named 'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'?
using ::isfinite;
      ~~^
```

The only 2 include directories I pass on my original command line exist and are:

```
$ ls -alF /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    12B Dec 17 11:54 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk@ -> iPhoneOS.sdk
$ ls -alF /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include
total 2160
drwxr-xr-x  169 root  wheel   5.3K Dec 17 12:07 ./
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  wheel   160B Nov  4 19:22 ../
 ...
-rw-r--r--    9 root  wheel    32K Nov  4 19:52 math.h
 ...
```

But the interesting bits here are the non-existing include directories it reports as well as the include directories it ends up searching eventually and their order. My guess is that additional directories not mentioned on the command line are inserted by Apple Clang's driver based on some Apple-specific logic.

You can see from the reported error that the `<cmath>` header is found at: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath` and at line 304 of it you can see:

```
#include <__config>      // Line 304
#include <math.h>        // This one ends up causing troubles
#include <__cxx_version>
```

Judging from the fact that in that same folder `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/` there is a file `math.h` that provides the necessary definitions, e.g.:

```
#include <__config>

#if !defined(_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_PRAGMA_SYSTEM_HEADER)
#pragma GCC system_header
#endif

#include_next <math.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus

// We support including .h headers inside 'extern "C"' contexts, so switch
// back to C++ linkage before including these C++ headers.
extern "C++" {

#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>

// signbit

#ifdef signbit

template <class _A1>
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
bool
__libcpp_signbit(_A1 __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT
{
    return signbit(__lcpp_x);
}

#undef signbit

template <class _A1>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<_A1>::value, bool>::type
signbit(_A1 __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT
{
    return __libcpp_signbit((typename std::__promote<_A1>::type)__lcpp_x);
}

...

#elif defined(_LIBCPP_MSVCRT)
...
#endif  // signbit
```

the authors of `<cmath>` were expecting the `math.h` from that same folder be included first and then the `#include_next <math.h>` directive find the system-specific `math.h`. That is not what's happening in reality however.

If you look at the first 2 entries in searched directories:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
```

you see that system-specific include directory ends up being above the Clang-injected standard library directory, which is why the system-specific `math.h` is being found, not the one in the same folder as the rest of the standard library headers. This is likely the case because if I explicitly add the standard library include directory to my command line BEFORE the other two directories `-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1` the problem goes away and I am able to compile the file. That's not what Clang's driver or whatever else is involved here does automatically: it adds that standard library directory via `-internal-system` (not sure what's the semantics of that internal flag) and it adds it AFTER the system directory.

Now if you look at the list of ignored directories, the very first entry in that list is:

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
```

of which the trailing `c++/v1` part does not exist on my machine, making me wonder whether the iPhone SDK installation was supposed to create a symbolic link `c++` inside the existing part of the path to point to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++` directory to make the whole thing work.

Anyways, this what I think is happening and I wonder if anyone knows how to properly fix this?

Thank you!

P.S. For the context:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
$ xcrun --show-sdk-path -sdk iphoneos13.2
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk
```

Comment: Thank you for your details explaination. But sadly no solution seems to work for my machine. I am about to goes for the final option to reinstall Catalina. Damn Apple, why they make things so difficult?

Comment: I followed these directions, from above, to hard code a path to math.h. That worked fine for a while but I suspect that a newer version of Xcode broke this and I was getting compilation errors involving math.h. So *don't* do this `Using #include</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h> instead of <math.h> in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath`!!!

Comment: On my side the problem was fixed by removing directory `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`. I was building Swift for Android on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 18):

You may try to use the CommandLineTools SDK rather than the XCode.app SDK.

I fix this problem when I compiling PointCloudLibrary (PCL)

```
#Check the current sdk
xcrun --show-sdk-path

#Change sdk
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools          #Using CommandLineTools SDK
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer   #Using XCode.app SDK
```

Also, reinstall XCode.app and CommandLineTools may help.

Comment: This IS the fix. Other suggestions like CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT or setting CPATH did not help.

Comment: I was facing a similar problem:
Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
on my Macbook Pro with M1 chip running Mac OS 12.4 Monterey with Xcode 13.4.1 & command line tools for Xcode 13.4 installed. 
Tried many other fixes but this fixes the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 17):

Using the command:

```sh
gcc -Wp,-v -E -
```

my #include <...> search sequence:

```
/usr/local/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

The reason of #include error is described below:

- `#include<cmath>` resides in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1`
- It includes `<math.h>`.
- It searches `/usr/local/include` directory as this is the first directory to search. There is a `math.h` in `/usr/local/include/c++/9.3.0/` directory
- It tries to use this.
- But expectation was to use the `math.h` of the same directory `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1`
- The `math.h` of `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1` include `math.h` of `/usr/local/include` using `#include_next<math.h>`
- As wrong `math.h` is included/linked with `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath`, the compilation error happens

The fix:

1. If we can alter the search order of `#include<...>` to search `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1` at first, it can be fixed.
2. Using `#include</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h>` instead of `<math.h>` in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath`

I have followed the #2 option and build is successful now!

And thanks to [solodon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59780819/5052841) for the detailed answer. I followed the answer to fix the issue.

Comment: Hi Niloy Datta! I suggest you to edit this answer removing the question from this answer and include only what answers. If you have a question, then ask separately in the proper way questions should be asked in this community.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁, removed it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked for me. Do you know a cleaner way to deal with this problem though?

Comment: @VictorSanchez, still trying to figure it out. Will notify once I get it.

Comment: The problem is that when using PCL I have to do the change but other times I just import cmath I have to reverse it

Comment: see my comment above about how hard coding a path to math.h is a bad idea.

Comment: Instead of 2, consider changing <cmath> to do `#include "./math.h"`. This avoids having to put the fully-qualified filename in there and still works (for me, at least).

Comment: No matter how I changed the include path order, I couldn't get <cmath> to load the right <math.h>. `#include "./math.h"` didn't work either. Only including the full path solved the issue for me. I hate that, it's going to give me headaches later on, but it's the only thing that worked for me. libclang must be doing something weird with the search path.

Comment: I'm using Cmake.  It worked for me to add ```set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk)```

Comment: I recently reinstalled command line tools, macos 12.2, ran `brew upgrade` and still had to do this! Option 2 above totally worked for me today, but why hasn't this been fixed upstream of me?

Comment: Perhaps useful to someone: to edit this file I ran `sudo vi /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath1`, added the new `#include` line, and closed with `esc` followed by `:x!`

Answer (score 6):

It is possible your copy of Xcode is corrupted. Check with codesign:

```
codesign --verify /Applications/Xcode.app
```

This happened to me, and the problem was corrupted Xcode. Reinstalling fixed it.

Something had modified the following:

```
file added: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__pycache__/scanner.cpython-37.pyc
file added: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__pycache__/decoder.cpython-37.pyc
file added: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__pycache__/encoder.cpython-37.pyc
file added: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
file modified: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/usr/include/math.h
file modified: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/math.h
file modified: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS.sdk/usr/include/math.h
file modified: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/math.h
file modified: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/math.h
file modified: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/DriverKit19.0.sdk/System/DriverKit/usr/include/math.h
file modified: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/include/math.h
file modified: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/usr/include/math.h
file modified: /Applications/Xcode-11.3.1-.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/math.h
```

`math.h` was empty in all the above places.

Answer (score 5):

I found that inside my project I have file `math.h`. After rename it the problem was disappear. Seams `cmath` include my file instead of system.

Comment: I had a similar issue due to a file called Math.h in `llvm/include/llvm/CodeGen/PBQP/Math.h` which gets indirectly referenced from cstdlib.

Answer (score 4):

@solodon's analysis is spot on. The issue is likely that the `cmath` file is including the wrong version of `math.h` based on the search order of the header files. At least, this is what was happening to me when I was getting the same error.

Scan your compiler output for `#include <...> search starts here:`. You can also force this output from the command line with [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22181943/305383):

```
gcc -Wp,-v -E -
```

It should look something like this:

```
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

Notice that the paths with `Toolchains` come before those with `Platforms`. If in your case the order is reversed, you need to figure out what in your configuration is causing this. For me, it was an explicit setting of `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` in my login script.

Offending code:

```
XCBASE=`xcrun --show-sdk-path`
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$XCBASE/usr/include
```

This was part of my attempt to work around Xcode 11 no longer providing the installation package for the SDK header files. After removing this code, I was able to successfully include `cmath` in my C++ code.

If you came here looking for solutions to this issue, you may require a different solution but hopefully this helps to shed light on what seems to be the root cause of this issue, header file search path order.

Comment: Are there any recommendations on how to fix this? I tried uninstalling both the command line tools and Xcode (11.4.1), but the `#include<...> search` order is still wrong.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to look in your login scripts such as `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc` etc. for things that can affect the search order such as compiler environment variables (in my case it was `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`) or the order of directories in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 4):

I have just got this error when trying to compile gRPC after recently upgrading to 10.15.4 and Xcode 11.4 and I started to look at all the solutions offered (here and [Can't compile a C program on a Mac after upgrading to Catalina 10.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15)), and tried a few of them (though not trying to recreate `/usr/include` as that would violate the separation that Apple were trying to create) - nothing seemed to work.

I then looked closely at the actual complier invocations that the `make` process was producing and noticed that there was an explicit

```
-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include
```

that was ultimately causing the includes to happen in the wrong order - removing this explicit include path allowed the compilation to succeed with a default install of catalina, Xcode and the Xcode command-line tools, as you would expect, no other tricks/compiler flags needed.

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. It turns out that some `pkg-config` files (e.g. libcurl) from Homebrew add this path automatically, even if you have Xcode installed. This was fixed in Homebrew 2.2.13. More details in https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/5068; PR that fixes this is in https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/7331.

TL;DR: Update homebrew

Comment: Yes it was an old homebrew pkg_config for zlib that was still somehow lying around, that was causing this for me - despite having an up to date homebrew and not currently  having a zlib installed anyway

Comment: Cause is same as @solodon mentioned.  Got this with MacOSX SDK as described here, picked up the SDK `usr/include` include due to CMake `find_package` getting e.g. zlib from it.  Fix was to put the toolchain `usr/include/c++/v1` folder onto the system includes (`-isystem` to clang, or `include_directories(SYSTEM ...)` in CMake). I deduced the toolchain directory off the CMAKE_LINKER path rather than hard-code it.

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me too. In my case, I had had such an explicit include in my Go CGO_CPPFLAGS environment variable, left over from a project that hasn't been updated to know where the Darwin stdio.h file could be found but llvm wasn't being used explicitly in that one, and I carried that over to a project that was already up to date with building from the latest Darwin but now, needing to have the LLVM c++/v1 files consistent with themselves, that explicit help of where to find Darwin headers was a problem. This was a huge help.

Answer (score 4):

Reinstalling Xcode, command tools and homebrew,
and

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include`

fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured out why this was affecting only some people. When Catalina came out, they stopped shipping the command line tools package with the /usr headers. A common workaround was to use CPATH to point to the system headers in your bashrc like this:

```
export CPATH=`xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include
```

However this appears to mess up the C++ include path ordering for cmath and math.h (as found in the other answers). The good news is that it seems that current homebrew builds of clang and gcc don't need CPATH set anymore to find the system headers. So you can just remove the CPATH override and be done with it.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting `MacOSX10.15.sdk` works.

In my case, it happened when I cmake llvm project and build the cmaked project in Xcode. This error was detected when compiling LibEdit.
I had successfully compiled this project on my MBP, but failed on my iMac. Both of them are the same macOS 11.3.1, Xcode 12.5, Command Line Tools 12.5, The same goes for other configurations.

So I compared the cmake log, and find the different:
On MBP, log For LibEdit was:

```
-- Found LibEdit: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include (found version ".")
```

On iMac, log For LibEdit was:

```
-- Found LibEdit: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include (found version ".")
```

This is what caused the build error.

The CommandLineTools directory files are Exactly the same:

```
MacOSX11.1.sdk,
MacOSX11.3.sdk,
MacOSX10.15.sdk,
MacOSX.sdk link to MacOSX11.3.sdk
MacOSX11.sdk link to MacOSX11.3.sdk
```

and Both Command Line Tools in Xcode - Preferences - Locations are set to Xcode12.5(12E262)

and I reinstalled Xcode and Command Line Tools on iMac. But no use.

the cmake command has specifies -`DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk"`. Still no use.

I don't know where else to set this. Finally, I deleted the `MacOSX10.15.sdk`, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

@mkl 's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58670035/3682709) helps to fix the similar issue on my side. Thanks.

## Issue and solution on my side

I got the same issue to compile a project on basis of [PCL](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl). The solution is to set CommandLineTools SDK CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT.

I tried @mkl's solution to do it in CMakeLists.txt, it doesn't work. So that I can only set it by `cmake .. -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk"`

**Another thing to mention:** there are two versions of command line SDKs in my MacOS:

```
~ » /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX
MacOSX.sdk/       MacOSX10.14.sdk@
```

`xcrun --show-sdk-path` gives out the default one, but actually only MacOSX10.14.sdk works on my side.

Discussion of the similar issue in PCL's repo:
https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/2601#issuecomment-621889211

## Difference between SDKs

I don't know much about cmake and SDKs in c++. The difference I noticed in cmake building log from different SDKs as following:

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX`:

```sh
-- Found OpenGL: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
```

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk`

```sh
-- Found OpenGL: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
```

On default:

```sh
-- Found OpenGL: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
```

Seems like the issue happens on SDK choice for Opengl.

## How to do it in CMakeLists.txt?

Appreciated it if anyone could advice.

Answer (score 0):

Summary: in my case, the build script was using an older version of `ios-cmake` toolchain (2.1.2), and updating it to 3.1.2 fixed the cmath/math include issue.

Adapting the nifty command proposed by @Ryan H. `gcc -Wp,-v -E -` for my case (clang, c++, iOs target)

```
clang -x c++ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk -Wp, -v -E -
```

yields on two Catalina including a virgin one where only tool ever installed is XCode 11.14.1:

```
 clang -cc1 version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59) default target x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

So the correct include path is the first non-ignored one, everything should work OK, but it didn't. It appears the issue came from an additional include command appended to the compilation call by the ios-cmake toolchain:

```
CompileC /Users/<...>/build.Release.ios/<...>.o <...>.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
-Isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk <...>
 -I/Users/<...>/Build_iOS/build.Release.ios/build.arm/Binaries/Release/include
 -Isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk/usr/include
 -I/Users/<...>/Build_iOS/build.Release.ios/build.arm/src/<...>.build/Release-iphoneos/<...>/DerivedSources/arm64
...
```

The culprit was the `-Isystem ...` line, which will cause the `#include <math>` line in the cmath file to end up loading the wrong file.
After much fiddling around trying to fix the cmake scripts, I noticed the older version of ios-cmake, and updating it had the 'only' effect of removing the unwanted `-Isystem` line - everything else was almost the same (apart from a few compiler option)

Answer (score 0):

Putting together solutions from Ryan H and Solodon solved my problem. Here's how I fixed it (Mac OS 10.15.7):

1. Make sure you have Xcode.app installed, and have opened it (which will install some additional stuff). We will be using the Xcode compilers to compile our code.
2. Go into your ~/.zshrc file and add the following lines to make sure the c++ compiler finds the header (.h) files it needs.

```
#############################
#Give C and C++ compilers directions to the right headers
#which are no longer in /usr/include, as expected.
#We should be using the Xcode.app libraries

XCOD="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

#Append to the front of the path (reverse order, second line ends up searched first)
export PATH="$XCOD/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include:$PATH"
export PATH="$XCOD/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/:$PATH"

#Append to the end:
export PATH="$PATH:$XCOD/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include"
export PATH="$PATH:$XCOD/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"

#Tell compiler to use this SDK's compilers to compile C and C++ code
MYSDK="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk"
export CFLAGS="-isysroot $MYSDK"
export CCFLAGS="-isysroot $MYSDK"
export CXXFLAGS="-isysroot $MYSDK"
export CPPFLAGS="-isysroot $MYSDK"
###########################
```

Then make these updates take effect by running

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

This will make the c++ compiler look for headers (such as math.h) inside Xcode.app in the right order. To verify this has worked, type

```
gcc -Wp,-v -E -
```

The result should display the path ending "/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin" before the one ending "/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include".

3. Open the file "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath" and replace the line

```
#include <math.h>
```

with

```
#include </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h
```

(This is line 304 on my system). This prevents cmath from trying to use a *different* math.h header file that exists elsewhere on the system and doesn't have some of the definitions that this cmath file expects it to.

4. This should be overkill at this point, but to avoid any possible confusion, you can move your other SDKs (such as /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk) somewhere outside your PATH. This prevents any possible conflict between the header files in this SDK and the header files with the same names in the Xcode SDK.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler tries to find `math.h` and usually it will find it under `/usr/local/include` first and then get a wrong one.

An easy way to fix it is to rename it using: `mv /usr/local/include/math.h  /usr/local/include/math_old.h`. Then the compiler would try the following include directories.

Comment: Your method is easy, but dangerous, because it  breaks the compiler system (OP may need it for other purposes than Catalina, and will certainly very soon forget about system changes he made). Moreover, it may work only until the next system upgrade. I would not touch the files that come with a compiler, and `/usr/local/include/math.h` is one of such files.

Answer (score -1):

Try modify cmath:
#include <math.h>  to #include "math.h"
The error is caused by include-path priority

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think, the last thing anyone should do, is to directly mess with system header files like `cmath`.

Comment: It is smallest change to your project. The error is just in this header and nothing else