# 'Error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace' while trying to run opensmile-2.3.0 on Mac OS Catlina?

Tags: macos, terminal, xcode11.3, audeering-opensmile

I'm trying install Opensmile-2.3.0 on Mac but I get few cmath errors. I have updated Xcode to 11.3 and it didn't help.

**Mac OS - Catlina 10.15.3**

I began by downloading the file as .tar file and unzipped it using

`tar -zxvf opensmile-2.3.0.tar`

Then changed the directory to opensmile-2.3.0.

Later started to follow the manual build instructions

```
bash autogen.sh

./configure
```

Everything runs fine till here and When I run the below command I get the following errors.

`(base) Suryas-MacBook-Air:opensmile-2.3.0 suryareddy$ make j4 ; make`

```
In file included from src/other/vectorOperation.cpp:58:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:318:9: error: 
      no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:319:9: error: 
      no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:320:9: error: 
      no member named 'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'?
using ::isfinite;
      ~~^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/math.h:749:12: note: 
      'finite' declared here
extern int finite(double)
           ^
In file included from src/other/vectorOperation.cpp:58:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:321:9: error: 
      no member named 'isinf' in the global namespace
using ::isinf;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:322:9: error: 
      no member named 'isnan' in the global namespace
using ::isnan;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:323:9: error: 
      no member named 'isnormal' in the global namespace
using ::isnormal;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:324:7: error: 
      no member named 'isgreater' in the global namespace; did you mean
      '::std::greater'?
using ::isgreater;
      ^~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:728:29: note: 
      '::std::greater' declared here
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS greater : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
                            ^
In file included from src/other/vectorOperation.cpp:58:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:325:7: error: 
      no member named 'isgreaterequal' in the global namespace; did you mean
      '::std::greater_equal'?
using ::isgreaterequal;
      ^~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:757:29: note: 
      '::std::greater_equal' declared here
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS greater_equal : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
                            ^
In file included from src/other/vectorOperation.cpp:58:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:326:9: error: 
      no member named 'isless' in the global namespace
using ::isless;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:327:9: error: 
      no member named 'islessequal' in the global namespace
using ::islessequal;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:328:9: error: 
      no member named 'islessgreater' in the global namespace
using ::islessgreater;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:329:9: error: 
      no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:330:9: error: 
      no member named 'isunordered' in the global namespace
using ::isunordered;
      ~~^
196 warnings and 13 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [src/other/libopensmile_la-vectorOperation.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catalina C++: Using <cmath> headers yield error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628377/catalina-c-using-cmath-headers-yield-error-no-member-named-signbit-in-th)

Answer (score 2):

uninstall xcode may work, it worked for my case, maybe some conflicts happened.

Comment: This worked for me.  I had to completely remove XCode and just have the command-line tools installed.  Thanks!