# Problems when building Drake from source with cmake

Tags: drake

I am trying to build and install Drake from source in order to get support for Mosek. I keep running into trouble, however. For the record, I am running macOS Catalina.

Right now my approach has been this:

1. Clone drake from github to a location on my computer (from https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake.git)
2. Install prereqs
   with `./setup/mac/install_prereqs.sh`
3. Run `bazel build //...` Make a
   directory called `build` and `cd build` `cmake ..` and then `make`
   and `make install`
4. And in my C++ project, which I build using cmake, I add this to CMakeLists.txt:
   `link_directories(drakelocation/build/install/lib)`
   `include_directories(drakelocation/build/install/include)`

However, when I try to build my project, I get an error that Drake is unable to locate Eigen: `'Eigen/Core' file not found`. I was able to work around this by adding:

`target_link_libraries(my_lib Eigen3::Eigen)` to my CMakeLists.txt

I found this a bit strange, as I expect that Drake includes Eigen when it is built, but at least this made me able to get a bit further.

After this I get a bunch of messages of the type:
`no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace`

i.e. it seems like Drake suddenly is missing all the standard C++ libraries. I have not  yet been able to fix this issue, so this is where I am currently stuck.

Do you have any suggestions, or have you encountered any similar problems before?

*Other information:*

- Using `find_package(drake)` does not work with my current approach at all (cmake is not able to locate drake-config.cmake). Am I missing something here that is required to make this work? Where does cmake expect libraries to be installed, and how do I install them in that place?
- I have also tried skipping the entire `bazel build //...` step, going directly to the `cmake ..` step, which did not seem to make any difference.
- In between every different build approach I have run `bazel clean --expunge` to make sure that nothing sticks around from the previous run.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell CMake where your Drake installation is located:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /absolute/path/to/drakelocation/build/install)
find_package(drake REQUIRED)

add_library(my_lib ...)
target_link_libraries(my_lib drake::drake)
```

This ensures you have all the necessary compiler and linker flags. Setting the include directory to simply `/absolute/path/to/drakelocation/build/install/include` is insufficient since it does not contain the include directories of the various dependencies of Drake.

Note that you do not need to call `bazel` yourself before calling `cmake`. When you run `make install`, it will call `bazel` internally.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jamie that solved the find_package() problem I had.

I still had some trouble with the build. Turns out that there was something wrong with my default SDK path, and that setting "CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT" according to this: [Catalina C++: Using <cmath> headers yield error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628377/catalina-c-using-cmath-headers-yield-error-no-member-named-signbit-in-th) after an update to XCode did the trick.

After this, I got a lot of strange error messages from Eigen, complaining that i.e. `MatrixXd` was not defined in the namespace 'Eigen'. For some reason, uninstalling it with `brew uninstall eigen` and then downloading and building eigen from source solved those problems.

It now works!