# Multiple issues with math.h on macOS catalina after upgrade

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, cmath

I have updated system to macOS catalina 10.15.6 and I was hitting issue described and solved by https://stackoverflow.com/a/61519060/3616359. I was hitting issues like:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/math/special_functions/fpclassify.hpp:552:17: error:
no member named 'isnan' in namespace 'std'; did you
mean simply 'isnan'
```

I simply replaced `<math.h>` by `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h` inside `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath`. However this causes another type of problems like:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h:764:42: error:
  no member named 'fabs' in the global namespace
```

The only way I compile my code is to modify `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath` twice during `make` invocation.

I also tried other suggestions from the same posted question, but didn't help.
Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be that you keep `#include<math.h>` and after that line also put `#inlude</Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h>` inside `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath` file.