# RStan not working, failing with: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13: command not found

Tags: r, xcode, clang++, rstan

```
library(rstan)
stan_nb <- rstan::stan_model("mything.stan")
```

I'm running the above and on the second line it fails, throwing the (below) error message and a pop up saying to install xcode developer tools.

I **DID** install xcode developer tools (i've done this multiple times). I installed R version 3.6.3 and  RStudio-1.4.1106.dmg.  I have xquarts and running **Mac OS X Big Sur 11.2.3** and have the gfortran compiler also installed.

Any ideas on how to fix this? not sure what to do at this point. There's a lot of information online and it would be helpful if someone has had this problem recently and knows of a solution.

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) -- "Lost Library Book"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
 
R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
 
  Natural language support but running in an English locale
 
R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.
 
Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
 
> library(rstan)
Loading required package: StanHeaders
Loading required package: ggplot2
rstan (Version 2.21.1, GitRev: 2e1f913d3ca3)
For execution on a local, multicore CPU with excess RAM we recommend calling
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores()).
To avoid recompilation of unchanged Stan programs, we recommend calling
rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)
> options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())
> library(rstan)
> stan_nb <- rstan::stan_model("mything.stan")
sh: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13: command not found
The NEXT version of Stan will not be able to pre-process your Stan program.
Please open an issue at
 https://github.com/stan-dev/stanc3/issues 
if you can share or at least describe your Stan program. This will help ensure that Stan
continues to work on your Stan programs in the future. Thank you!
This message can be avoided by wrapping your function call inside suppressMessages().
make cmd is
  make -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf' -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/make/shlib.mk' -f '/Users/bb/.R/Makevars' CXX='$(CXX14) $(CXX14STD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX14FLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX14PICFLAGS)' SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX14LDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX14LD)' SHLIB='file4f038d74992.so' OBJECTS='file4f038d74992.o'
 
make would use
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++14 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/"  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/"  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/BH/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/src/"  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/"  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppParallel/include/"  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP  -DSTAN_THREADS  -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  -include '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp'  -D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c file4f038d74992.cpp -o file4f038d74992.o
if test  "zfile4f038d74992.o" != "z"; then \
      echo clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++14 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -Wl,-rpath,/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libc++abi.1.dylib -L"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib" -L/usr/local/lib -o file4f038d74992.so file4f038d74992.o  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rstan/lib//libStanServices.a -L'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/StanHeaders/lib/' -lStanHeaders -L'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppParallel/lib/' -ltbb -ltbbmalloc -ltbbmalloc_proxy  -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation; \
      clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++14 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -Wl,-rpath,/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libc++abi.1.dylib -L"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib" -L/usr/local/lib -o file4f038d74992.so file4f038d74992.o  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rstan/lib//libStanServices.a -L'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/StanHeaders/lib/' -lStanHeaders -L'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppParallel/lib/' -ltbb -ltbbmalloc -ltbbmalloc_proxy  -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation; \
    fi
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/math/special_functions/math_fwd.hpp:879:9: note: 'isfinite' declared here   bool isfinite BOOST_NO_MACRO_EXPAND(T z);        ^fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]15 warnings and 20 errors generated.make: *** [file4f038d74992.o] Error 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system2(CXX, args = ARGS) : error in running command
2: In file.remove(c(unprocessed, processed)) :
  cannot remove file '/var/folders/cj/4rp2qqj549vc48lqqvkzsjtr0000gn/T//RtmpN0DoWO/file4f062d5a916.stan', reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a while, but I figured it out. Posting for posterior sake.

It turns out that Rstan has problems with Big Sur.  It's best to install the developer version as shown here: https://github.com/stan-dev/stanc3/issues/795

1. uninstall RStan
2. restart R kernel
3. Run

   remotes::install_github("stan-dev/rstan", ref = "develop", subdir = "rstan/rstan")

This will likely throw problems with cmath.  At a high level, there are problems with overwriting <math.h>.  The fix for it is here: [Catalina C++: Using <cmath> headers yield error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628377/catalina-c-using-cmath-headers-yield-error-no-member-named-signbit-in-th)

Replace:

```
#include</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/math.h>
```

with

```
 <math.h>
```

in

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath
```

This solved all my problems!