# Support for long long operations in C++ standard math library? (Apple silicon, macOS 11.3)

Tags: c++, c, macos, apple-m1

I've been beating my head against a wall for the past week trying to get a project to compile on my M1 Mac Mini (macOS Big Sur 11.4). Posting here rather than as an issue on the project Github page because this seems like a general toolchain issue. (Side note, I was able to compile the same code without any issues on my Win10 machine under WSL2 with a Debian-based distro and all the dependencies installed via apt-get)

Error (one of many, but all related to the long long variation of functions):

```
In file included from include/trick/Clock.hh:11:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string:506:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:668:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/typeinfo:60:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:81:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:85:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:148:12: error: no member named 'lldiv' in the global namespace; did you mean 'ldiv'?
  return ::lldiv(__x, __y);
```

I've tried following the advice from some comments in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628377/catalina-c-using-cmath-headers-yield-error-no-member-named-signbit-in-th) but none have helped.

- Installed XCode.app, changed the SDK path, and removed the CLT directory (I've since reverted to only having the CLT installed)
- Added `set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk)` to the project's `CMakeLists.txt`
- Explicitly setting clang, gcc, g++, etc... as the compiler in the `./configure` flags
- Explicitly including `-I/path/to/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include` in the CXXFLAGS set in ./configure

```
eric@Mac-Wahlberg ~ 
╰─$ clang -v                                                                                    1 ↵
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

╭─eric@Mac-Wahlberg ~ 
╰─$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

╭─eric@Mac-Wahlberg ~ 
╰─$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

╭─eric@Mac-Wahlberg ~ 
╰─$ xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk

eric@Mac-Wahlberg ~/Code/trick ‹15534f7› 
╰─$ gcc -Wp,-v -E -
clang -cc1 version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11) default target arm64-apple-darwin20.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.5/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

Some more terminal copypasta that may or may not be useful

```
╭─eric@Mac-Wahlberg ~/Code/trick ‹15534f7*› 
╰─$ cat /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/C++/v1/stdlib.h | grep "lldiv"
    lldiv_t                                                               // C99
lldiv_t   div(long long numer, long long denom);                          // C++0X
lldiv_t lldiv(long long numer, long long denom);                          // C99
#undef lldiv
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY lldiv_t div(long long __x,
  return ::lldiv(__x, __y);
```

Comment: What would really be useful to see is the source code, of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The error says "There is no `lldiv` in the global namespace", it's not required to be there, `std::lldiv` is supposed to be there on conforming hosted implementations from C++11. Try compiling with `-std=c++20` I don't have a problem on macOS 11 (can't speak for macOS 12)

Edit: Ignore the message above, it's only nitpicking.

Make sure you compile with `-std=c++11` or above. eg:

```sh
cd ~/Desktop;\
echo '#include <cmath>\nint main(){}' > main.cxx;\
xcrun -r clang++ -std=c++11 main.cxx -o Main;\
./Main && printf '%s\n' Success.
```

That should print 'Success.'

If not run this:

```sh
xcode-select -p
```

That prints the path to the Developer folder. If it's not:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

First run this

```sh
xcode-select --install
```

IF it doesn't say:
`xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`
stop where you are and update/install Xcode *from the Mac App Store*

Otherwise:

```sh
sudo xcode-select --reset && xcode-select -p
```

It should print `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: Um, the error is occurring in the standard header "stdlib.h", and, because it's a C header, `lldiv` should be in the global namespace. At best, this is a problem with the compiler installation; at worst, a problem with the compiler.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes but no. If you read the first error message you see that the c header is included from cstdlib `In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:85:` it's standard practivce for llvm devs to include the c header then adding IN the namespace std a lot of `using ::FooFromCheader` that said, the standard does NOT guarantee that any thing be included in the global namespace and you shouldn't rely on that. Also, if `lldiv` is defined in the global namespace, as far has C++ is concerned it doesn't have to be the one from stdlib