# Trouble compiling via Rcpp - headers not recognized?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I just finished re-installing both Xcode and CLT on my Mac running Big Sur 11.4. I'm working in RStudio Version 1.4.1717 with R 4.1.1

I then ran `devtools::has_devel()` to ensure things were installed properly and they weren't. I received the message

```
Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
```

Call `pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)` to diagnose the problem.

To fix the problem, I deleted my `Makevars` and now everything is OK.

```
Your system is ready to build packages!
```

However, upon attempting to `build()`, compilation fails and R throws several errors.

Here is one such error

```
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/Mac  OSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:321:9: error: no member named 'signbit' in the global   namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
```

It seems that Rcpp is not being recognized? Maybe the C++ headers...

I found this SO post, but it concerns Mac OS Catalina: [Catalina C++: Using <cmath> headers yield error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628377/catalina-c-using-cmath-headers-yield-error-no-member-named-signbit-in-th)

Any thoughts on how to solve?

Comment: I suspect you simply didn't follow the (sadly somewhat manual) installation steps for macOS.  Try for example this post https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/ -- but I am not sure if it is the most current. If in doubt, try the r-sig-mac list.  Rcpp tests fine at CRAN (and many other places) on properly configured systems.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I followed that link (and should have mentioned so). However, I will try again and if issues persist, will reach out to r-sig-mac list.

Comment: I recommend building up from the inside. Get Rcpp, and tools installed. The try `Rcpp::evalCpp("2+2")`; if you see the expected answer you have that right.  On for `gfortran` (if you need it), other libraries, ...  You can generally trust existing CRAN packages which should build at your end too.