# macOS Monterey c++ #include<cmath> error: no template named 'numeric_limits'

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, apple-m1, cmath

I failed to run a c++ program with a simple line `#include <cmath>` in it. The error shows

```
% g++ cmath-bug.cpp
In file included from cmath-bug.cpp:1:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:642:26: error: no template named 'numeric_limits'
    bool _FloatBigger = (numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits > numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits),
                         ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:642:60: error: no template named 'numeric_limits'
    bool _FloatBigger = (numeric_limits<_FloatT>::digits > numeric_limits<_IntT>::digits),
                                                           
......

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:664:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '_Lim'
    return _Lim::max();
           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:665:21: error: use of undeclared identifier '_Lim'
  } else if (__r <= _Lim::lowest()) {
                    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:666:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '_Lim'
    return _Lim::min();
           ^
11 errors generated.
```

I found some posts discussing similar problems but didn't get fixed.

```
My system version: macOS Monterey version 12.6

%xcode-select -p 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

%g++ -Wp,-v -E -                                         
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202) default target x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: Try `g++ -std=c++11 cmath-bug.cpp`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It gave the same output.

Comment: `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` might help.

Comment: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:642:26: error: no template named 'numeric_limits'` The path changes but the errors are the same, I guess they use the same library.

Comment: I finally solve the problem by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628377/catalina-c-using-cmath-headers-yield-error-no-member-named-signbit-in-th

Comment: @Peter, which answer on that page solved your problem? Thank you,