# Library to know headerfiles connections in sourcode

Tags: c++, c, connection

There is a library or something to create a graph of header dependencies of the sourcecode of a project.

For example, you have a class (class1.hpp and class1.cpp, cmethods.h and cmethods.c and the main program in mainFile.cpp).

Obtain a graph like this.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies

Comment: Your link helps me so much.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether include file heirachies are supported but you might want to check [Doxygen](http://sourceforge.net/projects/doxygen/) it does a source code analysis and is able to draw diagramms.

See also this introduction [Learning doxygen for source code documentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-learningdoxygen/).

If there are no conditional includes (#ifdef) you could also easily parse the source files by your self and generate an input file for [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).