# Is there a way to list all header files included in a c++ executable on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I understand that we can use nm to list the symbols in a file. But what I am looking for is to list all the headers that are included in a C++ executable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [/show include equivalent option in g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479049/show-include-equivalent-option-in-g)  (edit: Assuming you have the source to the executable, that is!)

Comment: @benjymous: This question is about already-compiled executables, not the compilation process.

Comment: If you want to list headers from source files, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976080/list-of-all-header-files-included-by-a-c-file – otherwise you're doomed, see Williham Totland's answer.

Comment: in an executable there is nothing such as "header"..do you mean the source files?

Comment: As explained in Williham Totland's answer, what you are asking for is not possible. Please explain why you want to do this, i.e. what problem you are trying to solve. Maybe then we can help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a way, and you don't need a tool for it; it's a static list:

- None. Ever.

During the compilation phase of making an executable or library, headers are included, not as symbols or dependencies, but textually. Their text is literally copied into the stream of code that is to be compiled, and their names are gone from the scrolls for all time.

Once this is done, the header files are never referenced again.

---

**Edit:** Guessing wildly here, but I'm thinking you probably want to know that libraries an executable uses; for which you can use the handy-dandy [`ldd`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ldd+1).

(As a point of interest, `ldd` won't give you statically linked libraries, so you might be out of luck anyway.)

Comment: I think sometimes it may be possible to get list of headers from DWARF data embedded in *debug* builds.

Comment: @el.pescado: Whether or not that can be considered part of the executable is an open question; and besides; it's not something you can trust to be present.