# Testprintenv:error while loading shared libraries:libodbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, solaris, dynamic-linking

I am trying to invoke a C-Program which returns the value for a given keyword from a configuration file

While trying to invoke program it's displaying below error:

```
**Testprintenv: error while loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
```

We have installed EasySoft previously and uninstalled back (Removed all directories).

Below dependencies are showing up on Linux machine
**

```
-bash-4.1$ ldd Testprintenv
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc0bdb000)
        libodbc.so.1 => not found
        libodbcinst.so.1 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000397b200000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000397ae00000)
```

**

When we try the same program on Solaris machine dependencies are showing up differently and executing without any error:

```
[Testuser]$ ldd Testprintenv
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        /platform/SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise/lib/libc_psr.so.1
```

Any insight why the dependency (libodbc.so.1) is only showing up on linux and how to resolve?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is printenv the only program on the Linux computer that has that error? If not, I'd look at the $LD_PRELOAD environment variable.

Comment: I assume the printenv you are talking about is not the standard printenv command because the standard one does not do what you have described. Did you compile it yourself? Where does it come from?

Comment: @harmic, printenv is not a standard command, I have renamed program name while posting here..

Comment: @TimM, $LD_PRELOAD is empty

Comment: What distro are you using? Have you install the libobdc package?

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there anyway to check the relationships between c executable and libraries other than ldd?*
>
> *Any insight why the dependency (libodbc.so.1) is only showing up on
>   linux and how to resolve?*

1) If you want to know *why* there is a dependency, I suggest to try finding common symbols. Unfortunatelly, you must have the libodbc library installed, because there is no way to find out from the `Testprintenv` binary which symbols are meant to be linked with this library.
So, do it like this:

```
# symbols needed by the Testprintenv binary:
nm -uD Testprintenv | tr -s " " | cut -f 3 -d" " > /tmp/symbols_needed

# symbols provided by the libodbc
nm --defined-only -D /lib/PATH_TO_YOUR_LIBRARY/libodbc.so.1 | cut -f 3 -d " " > /tmp/symbols_lib

# intersection of the two sets:
grep -w -F -f /tmp/symbols_needed /tmp/symbols_lib
```

The last command will list the symbols needed by Testprintenv and provided by libodbc.

2) *How to resolve* the issue?

- first, install the library (libodbc), does it work now?
- if not, make sure it is in the [standard directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922949/684229).
- if not, add the directory where libodbc resides to the LD_PRELOAD environment variable, like: `LD_PRELOAD=/home/ivan/my_lib/`

Comment: it's very useful, I am able to get the list of symbols needed by my program. But, there is no intersection of symbols provided by libodbc and my program...Any sight, why the dependencies are showing even we don't have any common symbols..

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti, you may use the same procedure to look at the other libraries, they might need libodbc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

First some explanation:

You are trying to use a software that REQUIRES [UNIXODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) .

By your OWN result of ldd it says:

```
**Testprintenv: error while loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
```

Now about LDD the man page says:

> ldd - print shared library **dependencies**

So this program you are trying to run **DOES NEED** the libodbc provided BY [UNIXODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/).
You may check rpmfind [here](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libodbc.so.1).

As Solaris is another platform it may or not use it. (as Solaris has others ways to handle what you are trying to do)

So please check the link and read the install section.

The reason your software is shared linked to UNIXODBC instead of static is

```
Dynamic Data Binding

This allows the user or the system administrator to easily configure an application to use any ODBC compliant data source. This is perhaps the single biggest advantage of coding an application to the ODBC API and to purchase these applications. Dyamic binding allows the end-user to pick a data source, ie an SQL Server, and use it for all data applications without having to worry about recompiling the application.
```

By using a non-static dependence easysoft user is able to connect to any database.

Comment: My program doesn't related to UNIXODBC. It's just reading a key-value pairs from a path and returning output. I have verified the #include statements also. Is there anyway to check the relationships between c executable and libraries other than ***ldd***

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies