# Error C2371 'DWORD': redefinition; different basic types

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I am getting this error "Error C2371 'DWORD': redefinition; different basic types" while compiling a Visual C++ code on Visual Studio 2015 using MFC.
When I double click the error it takes me to stdint.h line 23:

```
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;
```

And if I find any DWORD on my code and press f12 on it it takes me to minwindef.h line 156:

```
typedef unsigned long       DWORD;
```

I am not explicitly including any of those file, so I don't know in which order those files are being included.
I am quite lost here on what to do to fix this error. Does anyone have a clue?
If you need more info please ask me.

Comment: A) Did you make your own typedef for `DWORD`? B) Just because you do not include it explicitly doesn't mean one of the headers you do include doesn't as well.

Comment: What headers did you include?

Comment: @NathanOliver a)I am not defining DWORD myself b)I know, that's the problem, I cannot trace the code to where those headers are included.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I included hundreds of headers, I can't list all of them here.

Comment: In GCC `-H` would display the include tree. There must be some MSVC equivalent. Googling......... And here we go! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies

Comment: @user4581301 I had already set that option to show includes but even though I could'n find the file that it including stdint.h or minwindef.h. =/

Comment: @user4581301 When i try to find using ctrl+shift+f I select Entire Solution ( Including External Items ), and what I get are files from   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ , C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\ and C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\

Comment: Poking around, you'll find minwindef.h is pretty much unavoidable. It's pulled in by  windef.h which is pulled in by windows.h. stdint.h may or may not be avoidable, but should cause no harm. The question is where is  `typedef uint32_t DWORD;` defined. I was hoping that the include tree would make that easier to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, it was on a 3rdpartyapi.h:

```
#ifndef uint32_t
# define uint32_t DWORD
#endif
```

What I did was just include `#include <cstdint>` prior to the `#ifndef` and the error is gone.
Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Ha! I had it backward. It'a bloody macro.

Comment: @sergiol Yes I know, but when I click it shows "You can accept your own answer tomorrow"