# C++, Should I #include something if I need it *and* something else it includes?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

Let's say I have a header file called `foo.h`, and it includes another header, `bar.h`.

I also have a header file called `xyz.h`. It requires `foo.h` and `bar.h`, although `foo.h` and `bar.h` have nothing to do with each other, so I would feel weird to *just* include `foo.h` (which still compiles since it includes `bar.h`...

So, `foo.h` includes `bar.h`, `bar.h` *doesn't* include `foo.h`, but `xyz.h` *does* include `foo.h` and `bar.h`. Is this bad practice? Is there any reason why I shouldn't? Why am I able to do this?

Comment: It's common practice. You don't always know what other header files a header includes, so you include all the ones you need. [#include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) prevent problems if the same header is included twice.

Comment: Every header file should include *all* the headers that *it* needs ignoring whether or not they might get incidentally included through another header (because that can change).

Comment: Look up 'Include What You Use' via a search engine.  It should bring up http://include-what-you-use.org/ and https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use and other references.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That looks really useful, thanks for the link!

Comment: "...foo.h, and it includes another header, bar.h. ... ...although foo.h and bar.h have nothing to do with each other." - **This is weird.** If `foo.h` and `bar.h` have nothing to do with each other, why are you including `bar.h` in  `foo.h`?

Comment: @smlq Let me give an example from something I'm working on. Let's say I have a "Shader" class for OpenGL, and it includes the GLEW (extension wrangler) header. I also have a "Renderer" class which acts as a sprite batch. It must use `shader.h` *and* `glew.h`, but `shader.h` already includes it so technically I could just get away with only including it. Would that be bad practice, or do people often do similar things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each header should be self-contained. It should include all other headers it needs and have [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Suppose that the header was not self contained. Then if you wish to use that header in a different client, then the new client wouldn't even compile unless you found and pulled the need other headers.

There are also can be rare case when header file can be not self-contained, e.g. checks [Google's code style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Self_contained_Headers) for details.

Most of compilers support options for include dependency investigation. These options and other tools are discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies).

Comment: What you say in the first paragraph is true — it is often termed 'self-contained and idempotent'. However, this question is asking "what does it mean to be self-contained" when you get multiple headers involved. The issue is that a header A.h can be self-contained because it includes another header B.h, which in turn includes C.h, and C.h defines something that A.h uses. While B.h continues to need C.h, A.h is self-contained in the sense that it will work, but if B.h changes so that it no longer needs C.h but A.h does still need C.h, then A.h is no longer self-contained — because B.h changed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If `A.h` uses something that is defined in `C.h` than it should includes `C.h` or have a forward-declaration for used stuff. I understand it as "self-contained" header.

Comment: I understand; I agree.  But how do you demonstrate that A.h is not properly self-contained while B.h still includes C.h?  See [Should I use `#include` in headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486) for the C programmer's view on things, and some fairly effective ways of ensuring self-containment.  But the 'fairly effective way' is vulnerable to the A.h, B.h, C.h scenario outlined above — and there isn't a trivial way to avoid that.  See http://Include-What-You-Use.org/ etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, it' often a bit tricky to understand dependency without automatic tools.