# Is it possible to get the names of the included files of an object in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to instantiate an object from a class, let's say **Cat**, and know the names of its included files.

The main program should look something like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include "Cat.h"

    using namespace std;

    vector<string> getIncludes(Cat cat){
      ...
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      Cat cat;
      std::vector<string>list = getIncludes(cat);
    }
```

And the **Cat** class header file would be like this:

```
    #include "utils.h"
    #include "animals.h"

    class Cat{
    public:
      Cat();
      ~Cat();
      void meow();
    private:
      int age;
    }
```

After calling `std::vector<string> list = getIncludes(cat)`, `list` should contain `"utils.h"` and `"animals.h"`.

If there is another way to get those names in the main function I am open to suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/218910). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Why do you need the names of the included files? I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem (or, at least, in the wrong manner.)

Comment: An instance of a class does not "include" anything. Instances live at runtime, preprocessor directives even before compilation

Comment: And no, it's not possible.

Comment: Remember that there's compile time and run time. By the time the compile phase is complete, information about source files is generally already gone (i.e. already gone before run time). You should take some time to understand how C++ builds binaries.

Comment: All `#include` does is copy the file contents into the source code at the point of the `#include`.

Comment: It would have to be a preprocessor symbol. I don't believe any such thing exists.

Comment: @sircodesalot `#include` directives are for the preprocessor not for the compiler

Comment: Good point Tobi, thanks!

Comment: You could try *brute force* method by commenting out includes.  Comment out one include file and build.  If there are errors generated by commenting out, you know that the include is required.

Comment: "Is it possible to get the names of the included files of an object in C++?" : No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not possible, the information won't be present anymore at runtime.

The preprocessor simply replaces the contents of `utils.h` and `animals.h` at compile time at the place where the `#include` statements appear.

---

If you need such a list to detect dependencies for recompiling your code, most of the compilers can generate a list of the included headers in a translation unit.

Here's some further information how to do so:

- [GCC toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies)
- [MSVC toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137966/displaying-the-include-hierarchy-for-a-c-file-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Thank you @πάντα ῥεῖ I will find out how to get the info from the compiler, then.

Comment: @Camilo You should probably explain your actual use case that requires you doing that in your question. It really sounds like a XY-problem as stated in the 1st comment.

Comment: It is an XY-problem, I suppose. My use case is the following: I have a class with some private attributes that implement some interfaces (e.g.: a Cat that implements CatInterface) and, since I cannot access those attributes nor I know apriori what interfaces the classes will be implementing, I thought I could use Cat's header file to know what interfaces it is including.

Comment: @Camilo And how should listing the include files help about accessing the private attributes? I believe you should look up for dynamic polymorphism, and how to design the `Animal` interface instead.

Comment: To summarise: from a Cat myCat object I need to extract what interfaces its attributes are implementing. @πάντα ῥεῖ I don't need to access the private attributes, only know what interfaces they are using

Comment: @Camilo If your `Cat` class implements any interfaces like `Animal` you can check that either with [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) at compile time, or applying a `dynamic_cast` at runtime.

Comment: @Camilo Please formulate another question and specify exactly what you need to do. Also it's a bit unclear why you need to know what particular interfaces are used for attributes (sounds like another XY-problem right now).

Comment: I will rethink my problem and come back whenever I have a more specific question. Thanks a lot for your help! @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @Camilo As mentioned, you can provide a complete example code of what you have already, and what you expect to do it in another question. I believe your problem will be much easier to solve than you're thinking about it ATM.