# C++ Static Code Analysis - Show header used in statement or line

Tags: c++, header-files, dependency-management, static-code-analysis

I'm searching for a tool to get the used header (if there is one/more) for every line/statment in my c++ code.

Example:

```
#include<iostream> 
std::cout << "hallo";
```

The output i'd like to see:

> line 2: std::cout uses "iostream"

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies) question, the tools there do most of the part, they show dependency per file.

Does anyone know such a tool or how to acomplish this with the tools given in the answers in [the question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies)?

Goal: I'm checking code for the conformity to a standard which i have a list of allowed headers for. With the desired output I can create a metric saying something like: **60% of the code is using allowed headers, 15% is using other headers** or something like that.

Comment: This question is explicitly off-topic on stackoverflow. You may have some luck [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can use include-what-you-use for that with big verbosity

Answer (score 1):

This is not completely what you want but you can use Eclipse CDT to know where `std::cout` is declared.

If you press <kbd>F3</kbd> when `cout` is selected in Eclipse, you will jump to this line of code inside `iostream` header file on the system with gcc 7:

```
  extern ostream cout;      /// Linked to standard output
```

Comment: Thanks! That and the gcc -M flag are the way I'm doing it right now, but I'm searching for a more overall automated version. I added my goal to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com) to get all the methods called by a specific one with the location of each method called.

[image]